# how to display a keyboard on the screen

Tags: javascript, html

I have this,

```html
<!-- <script src="/index.js"></script> -->
    <div class="Boxen">
       <textz id="1">1</textz>
       <textz id="2">2</textz>
       <textz id="3">3</textz>
       <textz id="4">4</textz>
       <textz id="5">5</textz>
       <textz id="6">6</textz>
       <textz id="7">7</textz>
       <textz id="8">8</textz>
       <textz id="Q">Q</textz>
      <textz id="e">E</textz>
      <textz id="x">X</textz>
      <textz id="r">R</textz>
      <textz id="c">C</textz>
      <textz id="entr" style="width:70px">Enter</textz>
      <textz id="esc" style="width:70px">ESC</textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz id="w">W</textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
      <textz id="a">A</textz><textz id="s">S</textz><textz id="d">D</textz>
      <textz id="space" style="width:97%;">Space</textz>
</div>
<style>
.Boxen {
  top:1px;
  left:1px;
    width: 30%;
    background: rgb(0,0,0,.4);
    overflow-y: auto;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1000;
}

.Boxen > textz {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
    background: rgb(0,0,0,.5);
    margin: 5px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    color:black;
}
</style>
<script>
document.onkeydown = checkKey;
document.onkeyup = checkKey2;

function checkKey(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 49) {
    document.getElementById("1").style.background = "white"; 
  } else if (e.keyCode == 50) {
    document.getElementById("2").style.background = "white";
  } 
  else if (e.keyCode == 51) {
    document.getElementById("3").style.background = "white";
  } 
  else if (e.keyCode == 52) {
    document.getElementById("4").style.background = "white";
  } 
  else if (e.keyCode == 53) {
    document.getElementById("5").style.background = "white";
  } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 54) {
    document.getElementById("6").style.background = "white";
  } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 55) {
    document.getElementById("7").style.background = "white";
  } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 56) {
    document.getElementById("8").style.background = "white";
  } 
      else if (e.keyCode == 81) {
    document.getElementById("Q").style.background = "white";
  } 
        else if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    document.getElementById("w").style.background = "white";
  } 
        else if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    document.getElementById("a").style.background = "white";
  } 
        else if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    document.getElementById("s").style.background = "white";
  } 
        else if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    document.getElementById("d").style.background = "white";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 69) {
    document.getElementById("e").style.background = "white";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 88) {
    document.getElementById("x").style.background = "white";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 82) {
    document.getElementById("r").style.background = "white";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 67) {
    document.getElementById("c").style.background = "white";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById("entr").style.background = "white";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    document.getElementById("esc").style.background = "white";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    document.getElementById("space").style.background = "white";
  } 
}
function checkKey2(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 49) {
    document.getElementById("1").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)"; 
  } else if (e.keyCode == 50) {
    document.getElementById("2").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
  else if (e.keyCode == 51) {
    document.getElementById("3").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
  else if (e.keyCode == 52) {
    document.getElementById("4").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
  else if (e.keyCode == 53) {
    document.getElementById("5").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 54) {
    document.getElementById("6").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 55) {
    document.getElementById("7").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
    else if (e.keyCode == 56) {
    document.getElementById("8").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
      else if (e.keyCode == 81) {
    document.getElementById("Q").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
        else if (e.keyCode == 87) {
    document.getElementById("w").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
        else if (e.keyCode == 65) {
    document.getElementById("a").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
        else if (e.keyCode == 83) {
    document.getElementById("s").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
        else if (e.keyCode == 68) {
    document.getElementById("d").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 69) {
    document.getElementById("e").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 88) {
    document.getElementById("x").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 82) {
    document.getElementById("r").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 67) {
    document.getElementById("c").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById("entr").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    document.getElementById("esc").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
          else if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    document.getElementById("space").style.background = "rgb(0,0,0,.5)";
  } 
}
</script>
```

It works by itself but when I paste it in to moomoo.io (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) it doesn't work any more, this is a simple "keyboard" that shows what keys I press to show the people on YouTube. I'm not hacking or cheating for example. I just want it to work on any website I add the code too, thanks. (press the snippet, and hit <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>)

Comment: can anyone help? please!

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a problem description, though. Explain what you expect to have happen, explain what it does instead, and crucially, explain what you already did in terms of debugging and searching/researching. For more details on what you're expected to put in your post if you want good answers, see [the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not what you asked for, but I simplified your javascript code. I added all your key codes into an array, and then I simply do a look up.

---

If you want to inject this into Moo Moo:

- Open the developer tools (F12) while on moomoo.io.
- Copy the HTML code, including the `style` tag (second grey box below).
- In the Inspector tab: scroll to the bottom of the page:
- *Firefox:* Right click on `<div id="onetrust-consent-sdk">` and choose *Paste / InnerHTML*.
- *Chrome:* Right click on `<div id="onetrust-consent-sdk">` and choose *Edit HTML*. Paste the HTML code and click somewhere outside the HTML code.
- The keyboard should now pop up at the top left corner. Now it's time to bind some functionality to it.
- Click on the Console tab.
- Copy the javascript code (first box below). Paste it in the input, at the bottom of the page.

That would set you up with a working graphical representation of a keyboard.

[image: Console Explanation]

```js
var keys = [];
keys[13] = 'entr';
keys[27] = 'esc';
keys[32] = 'space';
keys[49] = 1;
keys[50] = 2;
keys[51] = 3;
keys[52] = 4;
keys[53] = 5;
keys[54] = 6;
keys[55] = 7;
keys[56] = 8;
keys[65] = 'a';
keys[67] = 'c';
keys[68] = 'd';
keys[69] = 'e';
keys[81] = 'Q';
keys[87] = 'w';
keys[83] = 's';
keys[88] = 'x';
keys[82] = 'r';

function checkKey(event, background) {
  let keyCode = event.keyCode;

  if (keys[keyCode]) {
    document.getElementById(keys[keyCode]).style.background = background;
  }
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => checkKey(event, 'white'));
document.addEventListener('keyup',   (event) => checkKey(event, 'rgb(0, 0, 0, .5)'));
```

```html
<div class="Boxen">
  <textz id="1">1</textz>
  <textz id="2">2</textz>
  <textz id="3">3</textz>
  <textz id="4">4</textz>
  <textz id="5">5</textz>
  <textz id="6">6</textz>
  <textz id="7">7</textz>
  <textz id="8">8</textz>
  <textz id="Q">Q</textz>
  <textz id="e">E</textz>
  <textz id="x">X</textz>
  <textz id="r">R</textz>
  <textz id="c">C</textz>
  <textz id="entr" style="width:70px">Enter</textz>
  <textz id="esc" style="width:70px">ESC</textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz id="w">W</textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz style="background:transparent;"></textz>
  <textz id="a">A</textz>
  <textz id="s">S</textz>
  <textz id="d">D</textz>
  <textz id="space" style="width:97%;">Space</textz>
</div>
<style>
.Boxen {
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 30%;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, .4);
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.Boxen > textz {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  float: left;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0, .5);
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: moomoo.io is a game, can you test the code here: https://moomoo.io

Comment: Hi! I got it to work. I edited my post with a better explanation on how you're supposed to make it work. Good luck, and happy hunting!

Comment: I am sorry I'm confused about the console part :/

Comment: the img seems to be blocked on my pc anyother website you can use so srry for the inconvenience.

Comment: i got the html and css in i just dont know were to add js

Comment: Nvm i got it thanks soo much sorry about the img problem.

Comment: its finky tho some times the wasd get stuck white any ideas?

Comment: It's because I toggle a class. I changed back so the code is changing the `background` through `style` instead.

Comment: Weird. It works for me, both in Mac Firefox and Mac Chrome. When you hit "Enter" after pasting the javascript code into the Console, it should say "undefined". You need to paste the javascript _after_ you pasted the HTML code.

Comment: oh, i was doing it wrong it works now thanks :)

Comment: how would i add a r-c (right click) and left click btn?

Comment: That would be a topic for another post. :) However, you can look at this, but replace `button.addEventListener` in the example with `document.addEventListener`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button